# Why can't I load this website except on Windows?

Tags: dns

http://www.battleswarmzone-.spruz.com/ fails to load on my system under ubuntu, but loads under windows. I can't ping this subdomain either, but spruz.com  loads fine.

Worse still, even proxies don't work, and worse even further: I can't load it with the firewall off either. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess because it's a malformed URI. I suppose windows isn't so careful about what it sends off to the dns. But I'm not at all sure about that!

When i do a manual DNS query, this comes back: http://72.233.54.145/ ("Sorry, 72.233.54.145 was deleted or has moved!") which possibly isn't that helpful. But it's the correct IP for this URI.

Comment: on Windows http://72.233.54.145/ is down but http://www.battleswarmzone-.spruz.com/ is up

Comment: any ideas on how to force ubuntu to load it without having to resort to reactos in a virtual machine (hahahaha)?

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome as well. I think it's safe to say this problem is caused by a bad website, not a problem in ubuntu or firefox.

Comment: Roland Taylor: If I'm right, this problem is caused by the lowest-level guts of the network infrastructure in ubuntu being well implemented. Not much you can do about that. :-) Sorry (hope I'm wrong)

Comment: I was thinking so myself. Really sucks for me I don't want to load vista just for a website. But I'm a guild leader on that game and I'm also the only person using linux with the skill to get other people to take interest.

Comment: I've tried a few of those web-proxy sites, none of which could resolve the host. Couldn't you ask them to remove the stray dash from the url?

Comment: This is weird! It browses on my Win work PC, but not in my Ubuntu guest vm. Googling the URL I can access other parts of the site though, and using Google language tools I can translate to view the page.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the owners of the site have enabled filtering based on OS detection and deny connections from Ubuntu machines? (Perhaps some security software thinking they're by default malicious?)

Comment: nope it's not that, spruz.com loads fine for me. In fact it's only that one that doesn't load.